# Combine every two lines while reading .txt file in python

Tags: python

I'm currently working with very large files in Python that look like

```
junk
junk
junk
--- intermediate:
1489       pi0     111 [686] (1491,1492)   
                             0.534    -0.050    -0.468     0.724     0.135
1499       pi0     111 [690] (1501,1502)   
                            -1.131     0.503    12.751    12.812     0.135
--- final:
 32        e-      11 [7]    
                             9.072    20.492   499.225   499.727     0.001
 33        e+     -11 [6]    
                           -11.317   -17.699  2632.568  2632.652     0.001
 12         s       3 [10] (91)  >43 {+5}
                             2.946     0.315    94.111    94.159     0.500
 14         g      21 [11] (60,61)  34>>16 {+7,-6}
                            -0.728     3.329     5.932     6.907     0.950
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
junk
junk
--- intermediate:
repeat
```

I want to combine every two lines after the "---final" line until the "----------------" line. For example, I'd like an output file to read

```
 32        e-      11 [7]      9.072    20.492   499.225   499.727     0.001
 33        e+     -11 [6]    -11.317   -17.699  2632.568  2632.652     0.001
 12         s       3 [10]     2.946     0.315    94.111    94.159     0.500
 14         g      21 [11]    -0.728     3.329     5.932     6.907     0.950
```

Notice how I'm omitting the extra entries in the lines without spaces. My current approach is

```
start = False
for line in myfile:
    line = line.strip()
    fields = line.split()
    if len(fields)==0:
        continue
    if not start:
        if fields[0] == "----final:":
            start = True
        continue
```

len(fields)==0 should end the script at the "---------" line and continue until it sees another "----final" line. What I currently don't know how do is combine the two lines together while omitting the extra information in the lines without spaces. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your desired output care about the spacing? For example would 
`32 e- 11 [7] 9.072 20.492 499.225 499.727 0.001` be too messy or can you split them with a comma?

Comment: That doesn't look too messy at all! I just want them all separated, either by space or by comma since I'd like to input it into another program and read the specific columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you know the exact lines that surround the section you want:

```
#split the large text into lines
lines = large_text.split('\n')
#get the indexes of the beginning and end of your target section
idx_start = lines.index("--- final:")
idx_finish= lines.index("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
#iterate through the section in steps of 2, split on spaces, remove empty strings, print them as tab delimited
for idx in range( idx_start+1, idx_finish, 2):
    out = list(filter(None,(lines[idx]+lines[idx+1]).split(" ")))
    print("\t".join(out))
```

Where `large_text` is the file imported as a giant string.

**EDIT**
In order to open the file `large_text.txt' as a string try this:

```
with open('large_text.txt','r') as f:
    #split the large text into lines
    lines = f.readlines()
    #get the indexes of the beginning and end of your target section
    idx_start = lines.index("--- final:")
    idx_finish= lines.index("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    #iterate through the section in steps of 2, split on spaces, remove empty strings, print them as tab delimited
    for idx in range( idx_start+1, idx_finish, 2):
        out = list(filter(None,(lines[idx]+lines[idx+1]).split(" ")))
        print("\t".join(out))
```

**Assumptions**

1. You know the lines that seperate the section of interest (IE: "--- final:" )
2. Your values are space not tab delimited. If not change `split(" ")` to `split("\t")`

**Should be the winner**
Added that formatting fix to the one set of lines. Same assumptions hold true.

```
with open('./large_text.txt','r') as f:
    #split the large text into lines
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    #get the indexes of the beginning and end of your target section
    idx_start = lines.index("--- final:")
    idx_finish= lines.index("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    #iterate through the section in steps of 2, split on spaces, remove empty strings, print them as tab delimited
    for idx in range( idx_start+1, idx_finish, 2):
        line_spaces = list(filter(None,lines[idx].split(" ")))[0:4]
        other_line = list(filter(None,(lines[idx+1]).split(" ")))
        out = line_spaces + other_line
        print("\t".join(out))
```

Comment: Hmm this looks promising. I'm not at my work station until tomorrow but I'll give this one a shot. Is there anything special to import the file as a giant string? I usually just open it with the read option. Also is there a way to keep only the first four entries of each line with this approach?

Comment: Gotcha, made edits to the answer to answer your questions and state some assumptions.

Comment: I'm trying this and it works, but my only problem is that it is including all the entries in the lines without spaces and outputting a file with misaligned columns. It's not very useful for what I'm working with.

Comment: Think i got what you were saying. Just a really simple formatting fix. 
Added it to the answer.

Comment: This is actually perfect! Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way of merging every other line:

```
for i in range(0,len(lines),2):

    fields1 = lines[i].strip().split()
    fields2 = lines[i+1].strip().split()
    print("\t".join(fields1[:4]+fields2))
```

Note that I considered here that all the lines to be merged are extracted and put in a list called `lines` and that I simply hard coded the number (4) of elements that will be kept from every first line.

Comment: This looks like it should work. I'll give it a shot tomorrow when I'm at my work station. Forgive the noobish question, but would this go before my final continue line while reading the file?

Comment: That loop would have to be outside your `for line in myfile:`. To use it just add a variable to store all the lines you want to merge during your main loop, then once you finish and exit that main loop, you launch the merging loop to merge the stored lines.

Comment: So I'm storing the lines with lines = [] and lines.append(line) within the loop, but every approach I try returns an index error out of range on the fields2 line. Any idea?

Comment: Check `lines` once you think it's complete to see if you have all the right lines, then check `len(lines)` to see if you have an even number of lines. Finaly try to see at what exact moment the error appears by printing `i` at the start of each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem with the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module and some regular expressions:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'''(?V1)
        (?:^---\ final:[\n\r])|(?:\G(?!\A))
        ^(\ *\d+.+?)\ *$[\n\r]
        ^\ +(.+)$[\n\r]
        ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

junky_string = your_string

matches = ["    ".join(match.groups()) 
            for match in rx.finditer(junky_string)
            if match.group(1) is not None]
print(matches)
# [' 32        e-      11 [7]    9.072    20.492   499.225   499.727     0.001', 
#  ' 33        e+     -11 [6]    -11.317   -17.699  2632.568  2632.652     0.001',
#  ' 12         s       3 [10] (91)  >43 {+5}    2.946     0.315    94.111    94.159     0.500', 
#  ' 14         g      21 [11] (60,61)  34>>16 {+7,-6}    -0.728     3.329     5.932     6.907     0.950']
```

This looks for `--- final:` at the very beginning of the line or spaces, followed by digits **after** having matched `--- final:` (study the [**explanation on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/nY0uH4/1) for more details).
The matched items are joined with a tabulator afterwards.